# 2dsphere index in MongoDB collection is not fetching in spring Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have the same issue than [here][1]. I have created an index "`2dsphere`" but while fetching from spring Java it is telling me to create an index on that specific column to trigger `find()` geospatial query on that. Can you tell me how to fetch geospatial index from spring Java?

This is my collection structure in mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5729f6f0daf5583ade68b277"),
"type" : "Feature",
"geometry" : {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                -61.392147064209, 
                12.5836229324341
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.3972930908203, 
                12.5838899612427
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.401252746582, 
                12.5869073867798
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.3977165222168, 
                12.5903301239014
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.3904685974121, 
                12.5893573760986
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.388843536377, 
                12.587965965271
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.3890991210938, 
                12.5845184326172
            ], 
            [ 
                -61.392147064209, 
                12.5836229324341
            ]
        ]
    ]
},
"properties" : {
    "TZID" : "America/St_Vincent"
}
}
```

and the query to create index query:

```
db.timezone.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})

@Repository
public class MongoDaoImpl extends BaseMongoDaoImpl implements MongoDao{

public static final Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public String getTimezoneIdFromLatLong(Double lat, Double longi){
    String TZId=null;
    try{
        Query query = new Query(new Criteria()
                        .and("geometry")
                        .near(new Point(lat, longi)).maxDistance(0)).limit(1);
        query.fields().include("properties.TZID").exclude("_id");   
        logger.info("Mongo query : " + query.toString());
        TZId =  mongoTemplate.find(query, String.class,"timezone").get(0);

        logger.info("Getting the TimezoneId of Lat and long : "+ TZId);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception occured while getting TimezoneId from lat & long", e);
    }
    return TZId;

}
}
```

So, I m trying to run the above code then it is giving me the below error in console.

> 2016-06-03 12:15:52,185 [http-nio-8321-exec-3:a7827b0e-eb2e-4485-a385-e6a8a1dd765d] INFO  :::, - Mongo query : Query: { "geometry" : { "$near" : { $java : Point [x=-61.338249, y=12.691054] }, "$maxDistance" : 0.0 } }, Fields: { "properties.TZID" : 1 , "_id" : 0}, Sort: null
>
> 524e89638c4d] ERROR :::, - Exception occured while getting TimezoneId from lat & long
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=services.timezone limit=1Tree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=0 isNearSphere=0
>   Sort: {}
>   Proj: { properties.TZID: 1, _id: 0 }
>    planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=services.timezone limit=1Tree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=0 isNearSphere=0
>   Sort: {}
>   Proj: { properties.TZID: 1, _id: 0 }
>    planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server localhost:27017
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2114) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]

Comment: Hi Priyanka, this is off topic for Stack Overflow, can you show what you have tried and if you are stuck we can help. See our [on-topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

After so much struggle i found answer without using Criteria. This below is using not using spring...i.e. only java This is definitely gonna help u out

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017 );
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("services");
DBCollection collection=  db.getCollection("timezone");
BasicDBObject point = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point");
double[] ptCordinate={lat,longi};
point.put("coordinates", ptCordinate);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
    "geometry", new BasicDBObject(
        "$near", new BasicDBObject(
            "$geometry", point
        )
    )
);
collection.findOne(query);
```